# Подписи домов и улиц на собственных картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть 2 вопроса:

1. Есть ли возможность добавить номера домов, название улиц и др. надписи на собственные карты?
   Есть карта здания со своей подлодкой, необходимо добавить номера кабинетов, как это можно сделать? Статику через фш не очень выгодно делать, так как могу ошибаться, а переделывать тайлов не хочется  . Через геоколлекции меток можно, но хотелось бы других вариантов
2. Как реализовать отображение меток по слоям? Т.е. на моей карте здания имеются этажи, есть фильтр меток, как показывать определенные метки только на определенных этажах(слоях)?

Comment: Через геоколлекции или objectManager нормальный вариант решения первой задачи. Фильтровать метки удобно в objectManager с помощью метода setFilter https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#setFilter-param-filterFunction

Comment: У меня используется фильтр меток для отображения и скрытия. Что-то типа меню. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы я нажал на значок и появились все метки, привязанные к нему, это реализовано, только вот нужно еще, чтобы метки с других этажей не было видно. Не пойму, как фильтрацию прикрутить к типам карты. Спасибо!

Comment: @ЛесничинАнтон конкретно по типу подложки фильтровать объекты нельзя. Через setFilter можно прикрутить кастомный фильтр и по клику шоу/хайдить ваши объекты.